# How to extend storage space on VPS (LVM) 9GB to 40GB

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, lvm, vps

My VM came with a 9GB setup but a 60GB drive. I'm trying to extend it to it's full size. I have to do this on several servers. I tried to follow a guide else where but when creating a new partition I got this msg.

> If you want to create more than four partitions, you must replace a
>   primary partition with an extended partition first.

Here is some info you might find handy to help.

```
root@ubuntu:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  584K  395M   1% /run
/dev/dm-0        57G  3.0G   52G   6% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1       134M   68M   57M  55% /boot

root@ubuntu:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 62.9 GB, 62914560000 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 60000 cylinders, total 122880000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00096132

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      292863      145408   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          292864     2246655      976896   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3         2246656    20969471     9361408   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda4        20969472   122879999    50955264   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/CAC_VG-CAC_LV: 61.8 GB, 61761126400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 7508 cylinders, total 120627200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes 
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/CAC_VG-CAC_LV doesn't contain a valid partition table`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need additional info feel free to ask. I will be watching all morning.

Thanks

Edit- I'm actually thinking that script I ran earlier worked and did extend the drives, but one server has that partition error and the other doesn't.

Edit - Fstab output

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/CAC_VG-CAC_LV /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0      1  
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=1d92b194-7885-4b25-a4ba-a7b8683229e1 /boot           ext4  defaults 0 2
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=be7625e5-2e2c-41f2-8d5f-331f90980b9e none            swap    sw  0 0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

pvdisplay and vgdisplay

```
root@ubuntu:~# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               CAC_VG
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  7
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               57.52 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              14725
  Alloc PE / Size       14725 / 57.52 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               A4SRwW-Vqpz-qRLf-iXIm-yKny-tcyI-wYTMdg

root@ubuntu:~# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda3
  VG Name               CAC_VG
  PV Size               8.93 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2285
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          2285
  PV UUID               al3A0j-NEpg-yjRd-2yzF-pMUm-fa42-XdcZmc

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda4
  VG Name               CAC_VG
  PV Size               48.59 GiB / not usable 1.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              12440
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          12440
  PV UUID               phIhtw-wze3-IOTU-oiik-586P-ecJP-5KY913
```

Edit- Output of script cloud host said to run

```
root@ubuntu:~# sh zang.sh
Error: Can't create any more partitions.
Error: Partition doesn't exist.
partition: none, disk: /dev/sda, lower: 0, upper: 0
/dev/sda: partition table type 'dos' detected
partx: /dev/sda: adding partition #1 failed: Device or resource busy
partx: /dev/sda: adding partition #2 failed: Device or resource busy
partx: /dev/sda: adding partition #3 failed: Device or resource busy
partx: /dev/sda: adding partition #4 failed: Device or resource busy
partx: /dev/sda: error adding partitions 1-4
  Device /dev/sda5 not found (or ignored by filtering).
  Device /dev/sda5 not found (or ignored by filtering).
  Unable to add physical volume '/dev/sda5' to volume group 'CAC_VG'.
  New size (9725 extents) matches existing size (9725 extents)
  Run `lvextend --help' for more information.
resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
The filesystem is already 9958400 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

As you can see it looks like it doesn't work but when logging in I go from this

```
Usage of /:  13.1% of 8.66GB   to    Usage of /:   3.1% of 37.27GB
```

Thanks once again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure is rather easy and it should even work on a running system.  Keep the word "should" in mind.  Normally, the procedure is as following:

- Start off with resizing the LVM you need to resize:  `sudo lvresize -l 100%FREE /dev/vg00/myvolume`  This tells LVM to use up all free space to enlarge the volume `/dev/vg00/myvolume`
- Now you need to resize the filesystem contained within: `sudo resize2fs /dev/vg00/myvolume`  It should detect that you have the disk mounted any then use it's online resizing mode.

That's it... You're done.

Did I tell you to backup your data before doing all that?  Here you go: backup your data before doing this.

Note that your output says something about a volume being about 61.8GB.  The output of both `lvdisplay`, `vgdisplay` and the contents of  `/etc/fstab` might give additional information regarding your system.  I'm also not very certain why you have two LVM marked partitions.  Did you create those?

Comment: No they all come with the VM upon creating it. My other servers all look similar.

Comment: Can you give me the output of `sudo pvdisplay` and `sudo vgdisplay`?

Comment: I added it to the post

Comment: I'm pretty sure after looking over all this the script I ran before I made this post worked. I do believe the drive has been extended now. I don't know what I get that partition error though.

Comment: Thanks for the update... I just noticed something.  In your fstab, it says that your root filesystem is `/dev/mapper/CAC_VG-CAC_LV` (this translates to `/dev/md0`, which you can check by issuinging `ls -la /dev/mapper/CAC_VG-CAC_LV`.   Furthermore, if you look at your   `df -h` command, your root partition is ...  `/dev/dm-0        57G  3.0G   52G   6% / `.  That means you already have your 60G mounted as root.  Those "missing" 3G, are the /boot and the swap parition.  I would conclude it is all in order.

Comment: Yes, it look absolutely as if it worked fine.

Comment: The partition error is normal.  `fdisk` thinks it is a block device like a normal disk, and as such it tries to read the partition table of that disk.  However, it is **not** a normal disk, but a volume containing a filesystem.  Due to this, there is no partition table it can read.  It issues an error, but the error is irrelevant.  You can safely ignore such errors on LVM volumes.

Comment: Just a little word on the two LVM partitions.  They are the physical disks (`/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda4`) that together form the volume called `CAC_VG`.  You can see that the size of `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda4` (as seen in the `pvdisplay`output)  add up to the size of `CAC_VG` (as seen in the `lvdisplay` output).  No idea why exactly they chose to do it that way.

Comment: Well I really appreciate your help. I think the servers needed rebooted or something for it to appear or most likely I was doing it wrong. I don't understand linux file systems much. I was worried I was going to do permanent damage. I'm trying the script on one last server to see if it works.

Comment: You're welcome.  Normally a reboot should not be required to do this.

Comment: It wasn't required, but the only way I could see the space was to log in and log out because of my lack of Linux skills.... Check the update at the bottom of my questions to see what I mean. I also added the output of that script so you can see why I freaked out and made this question.

Comment: I can understand the confusion.  Well it works now. Off to new adventures! ;-)